# How to correctly place sticky td element in table

Tags: html, css, html-table, hover, sticky

At the end of the table(last td) i have a button, that shows pop-up window with additional options. I want this td/button to be at the end of the row, but when screen is small(appears
X-axis scroll) i want it to stay in the end of the visible part of table. I did it by putting those styles to td:

```
td {
  position: sticky;
  right:0
}
```

It worked, but now if you hover pop-up window(that appears after click) in a special area(above the same button, but from another row) window disappears. I tried to add z-index to pop-up window, but it did not work. Does anyone know how to fix it, or should i use different styles to position td/button?

Pop-up menu:
 [image: Regular pop-up]

 Moment before disappearing: 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

try margin-top:-5px . or try to add parent to your element and transfer your style to parent. than to child you must add position:relative and top:-5px

Answer (score 0):

Just Try z-index 0 or -1 to the td{}. I hope it will work fine.

```
td {
  position: sticky;
  right:0;
  z-index: 0; //or below one
  z-index: -1;
}
```